Issue with DBSAT Tool Stuck at "Setup Complete" Stage
We want to perform a security assessment on our database using the DBSAT tool. However, we are facing an issue. When I run the DBSAT, it gets stuck at the "Setup complete" stage and does not progress.
Do you have any advice to solve this issue?
https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/dbsat-stay-for-hours-in-the-stage-setup-complete-2483

After leaving it for probably 4 hours DBSAT successfully generated an output.
